# Whitespace default value for Complex type mixed=true

Tags: xml, xsd, whitespace

I have a schema that gives me this definition, and nowhere in the schema is there any reference to whitespace (never specifies preserve/collapse/replace on anything).

```
<xs:element name="Content">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I've run into some code that is doing a .trim() on the string produced during parsing of this element. If this implies a whiteSpace value of `collapse`, the trim() would seem to be valid, but if it implies `preserve` or `replace` the trim() would be a bug. 3rd party code elsewhere appears to be treating it as `preserve` but I've got little confidence that that was a reasoned decision based on the schema.

Removing the trim is what I need to do to make our code match their code so my path is clear, but I've become curious whether or not the existing behavior was technically correct (if not there are other places in the code that may need to be touched up).

I've spent time googling and a half an hour or so picking through the xml schema spec and not found a clear answer, so before I spend a lot more time there, ferreting out what is probably an implied default based on a combination of 2-3 areas of the spec, I thought I'd ask here in the hopes that someone has tracked this down already and just *knows* the answer. (or someone gets curious and tracks it down for fun).

Answer (score 0):

The `whiteSpace` facet can be used to constrain the value space of types derived from string; it does not direct an XML parser to trim or normalize string values.  Think of it as specifying constraints on the validity of the components of an XML document, not as directing changes to the parsed values of those components.

Comment: It's a bit more complex than that. In the XSLT/XQuery context, whiteSpace changes the typed value of a node to be collapsed/normalized, but it does not change the string value. At the PSVI level the terminology is different, but the effect is similar.

Comment: @MichaelKay: I interpreted OP to be implying that a whiteSpace declaration in an XSD could affect trimming of a string produced during parsing of an XML instance document.  Perhaps I misunderstood.  Tell me though, am I wrong to think that it's only validation, not retrieval, that's affected by a whiteSpace declaration in an XSD?

Comment: The whitespace facet affects the "actual value" of a node in the PSVI. But of course most people doing validation are only interested in knowing whether or not the document is valid, they aren't going to look at other PSVI properties of nodes. Probably they're most likely to use the PSVI if they're using schema-aware XSLT or XQuery, in which case the PSVI "actual value" becomes the XDM "typed value".

Answer (score 0):

The whiteSpace facet applies only to simple types, so I can't see how it is relevant to your mixed-content complex type.

In the conventional usage of mixed content to represent marked up document text, whitespace is generally significant. Certainly, there is no way of declaring in the schema that it isn't significant. But your application may know more about the data than is stated in the schema; only the application can know whether it's safe to trim whitespace.